# Qt QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItem events

Tags: qt, events, resize, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I've got some QGraphicsObjects which are dependent of the size of the scene they are on. So my graphics object needs to know when two events occur:

1. When it is added to the scene
2. When it's scene is resized

The way I do it now is - create 2 signals in scene's parent: obj_create, scene_resize. And connect them to the slots of the gr.object. It seems to be not the best way. I can't find any event like *addedToScene* or *sceneResized* in the QGraphcisItem...

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to read the doc little bit accurately... Hope it helps someone...

```
QVariant        itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{

    if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSceneHasChanged)
    {

            this->performSomeUpdates();
            QObject::connect(this->scene(),SIGNAL(sceneRectChanged(QRectF)),this,SLOT(sceneRectChanged(QRectF)));

    }

    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one of two possible ways: Either subclass QObject in your GraphicsItem and simply use Signal/Slots or define your own interface, lets say IResizableEvent with a resize method. In your GraphicsItem you implement the method with your resize code. When you detect a scene resize in your Scene class, just iterate over all items, cast them to the interface type and call the resize method.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but there actually is a special event in QGraphicsItem for that needs...